# How to write stored Proc in SQL server to input one column from table and return back same column and flag column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My requirement is to pass a list of `phonenumbers` from a table and the output I require is to get `phonenumber` column back and `IsMobile` column.

My proc logic should be: when I pass the `phonenumber` column in to the stored procedure, it should check with other `table B` having column `MobileNumbers` (which has database of mobile numbers).

If the `phonenumber` passed matches with the list in `table B` then I need to flag `Ismobile` column `'1'` and if the phone number passed is not in the `table B` then `'0'`.

Here is the source table example

[image]

Now I have a another table B (which are the list of Mobile Numbers)

[image]

When i pass my source table `phoneNumber` Column  as an input  and  find any matches in `Table B` then I need to Flag as 1.

here is how I want my return values from the stored procedure must be

[image]

Please help me with the stored procedure

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so what have you tried?

Comment: This is a very clear and well-illustrated question, but it shows no research effort.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one approach:

```
select s.*,
       (case when exists (select 1 from mobiles m where s.phonenumber = m.mobilenumber)
             then 1 else 0 end) as HasMobile
from source s;
```

In my opinion, there is zero reason to make this a stored procedure.  You can create a view or inline table function if you want to encapsulate this logic with a name.